# Specific element from an array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, mouseevent, d3.js, attr

So my question here is two-fold. Let me say that I am very new to d3 and javascript and so forgive me if my questions seem very simplistic.

First, I create an array with my data that looks as follows:

```
    var data=[
{
    "atomic_number": "1",
    "name": "H",
    "en": "2.2",
    "type": "non-metal"
},
{
    "atomic_number": "3",
    "name": "Li",
    "en": "1",
    "type": "metal"
}
  ]
```

I also have a svg canvas created:

< svg id = "canvas" xmlns = "LINK" version=  "1.1"  >

So I do the following with d3:

```
            var selection=canvas.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data_var)

            selection.enter().append("circle")

             selection
                .transition().duration(800)
                    .attr("id", d.name)
```

My first question is, is it legal/okay to give each element in my data array an id the way I did here by doing attr("id", d.name")? If it's not, how would I go about giving each element its own id?

My second question has 2 parts:

a- assuming I correctly applied an id to each element, how do I go about accessing said element later? Can I just do var my_var = d3.select("#id")? Because I tried doing that and it didn't seem to work. Do i somehow have to fish it out of my data array?

b-Assume I have all the elements in my data array displayed as circles on the screen. How do I make it so that if I click on one of them, a function that will operate on that specific element/circle is called?

Answer (score 0):

1st question: What you're doing is almost fine but the way you stated the question seems to suggest you need a bit of clarification of what is going.

First of all you need to make the distinction between data elements and graphical representations of the elements. When you do a select (and bind it to data using the data() call) you actually select the *graphical* representations of the bound data, in your case the svg:circle elements.

What is a bit strange here is your transition call on selection. It is wrong and it is weird. It is weird because you're changing a non-visual property and use a transition for that, I don't see why you would do that. Second, it is wrong, to access the data, bound to an element you'll need to pass in a function like this:

```
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name;} )
```

I'd rewrite your code as follows:

```
var data = ...;
var selection = canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data);
selection.enter()
  .append("circle")
  ... // Don't forget the attributes that actually set the size/pos of the circle
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; } )
```

2nd question:

a) Yes you can indeed access elements liked that by id, but it didn't work for you because of the error I pointed out in the previous section. However, in many cases it should not be needed to access individual elements. I'm not sure what you want to do with individual elements so if you could elaborate on that.

b) You'll have to install event handlers:

```
selection.enter()
  .append("circle")
  ....
  .on("click", function() { console.log("I was clicked"); });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I understand a lot better now. 

One thing though is that using .on("click", function(){}); doesn't seem to be working for me. None of my circles get drawn when I write it.